# how to pass my listbox items remove to my combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

Hello Good Evening everyone... im looking for help i have a problem.. how can i pass again my datas in combo box when i remove it from listbox ? 
first

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(comboBox1.Text == "withTax")
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        withtax.Text = "Yes";
        comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox1.Text);
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "SSS")
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        SSS.Text = "Yes";
        comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox1.Text);
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "PhilHealth")
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        PhilHealth.Text = "Yes";
        comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox1.Text);
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "Pag-Ibig")
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        Pagibig.Text = "Yes";
        comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox1.Text);
    }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = listBox1.SelectedItems.Count -1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[i]);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Items.ToString());
    }            
}
```

Comment: `comboBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString());`

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array. the error sir

Comment: Put this before `listBox1.Items.Remove....`

Comment: comboBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString()); sir ? chetan?

Comment: `comboBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString()); listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[i]);` like this

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: it worked thanks bro

Comment: sir when i remove i want to display NO to my set labels to them how to do the if statement ?

Comment: hold alt and press print screen to get a screen shot of the selected window, you can then paste images into the text box when asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch these two lines

```
listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[i]);
comboBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Items.ToString());
```

like this

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Items.ToString());
listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[i]);
```

In the first line your removed it from the listbox items then you can't use it, you should switch them this way.

and change this

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Items.ToString());
```

to this

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString());
```

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: sir when i remove i want to display NO to my set labels to them how to do the if statement ?

Comment: You can add a method like this
`private void changeToNo(string item)
{
    if(item == "withTax")
        withtax.Text = "NO";
    else if (item == "SSS")
        SSS.Text = "NO";
    else if (item == "PhilHealth")
        PhilHealth.Text = "NO";
    else if (item == "Pag-Ibig")
        Pagibig.Text = "NO";
}`

and call it before the two lines
`changeToNo(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString()); //here
comboBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString());
listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[i]);`